# Vim-Latex: Inverse and Forward Searching partially enabled. (Environment: Vim-Latex Suite, Sumatra, MikTex)

Tags: vim, forward-inverse-search, pdfsync

This is a question directed to those who are familiar with compiling Tex using Vim. My OS is Windows 8.1

**Problem Description:**
Inverse and Forward Search is partially enabled. When I double click at a paragraph in the PDF file (in Sumatra), if I double click at the first sentence, then I can be sent back to the corresponding paragraph in `.tex` file opened in Vim. However, if I click at any line further than (including) the third line of the same paragraph, I would be told that:

```
No synchronization info at this position.
```

The weird thing is, after a random number of lines, inverse search would again point to the `.tex` file again.

For forward search, I can only say the following:

1. Sometimes, for the paragraph where inverse search is partially enabled, it works by sending the focus of window to the PDF document and pointing to exact corresponding paragraph.
2. Sometimes, forward search will send me to a random paragraph in PDF file.
3. And sometimes, the forward search fails. Sumatra complains that:

   `No result found around line # in file ~\kkk.tex`

My Vim is on Github: https://github.com/llinfeng/Vim-Win.

I am not sure if I am asking this question in the correct forum. If not, please direct me to the correct site/forum/mail-list.

Answer (score 1):

This question had been resolved. Do not use the `pdfsync` package. And this solves all the synchronization issues.

I discovered this solution while I am constructing a minimal document that repeats the problem.

Again, you are welcomed to use my distribution of Vim on Github to compile your tex files.